In Prometheus, is it possible that at same timestamp the defined PromQL is evaluated as true but alert is not firing?
I recently encountered a problem that struggle me several days...
I've defined a PromQL in rule yaml in expr, and for is set as 0s (firing immediately). Global evaluation_interval is 1m and query.lookback-delta is 2m. I manually queried this predefined PromQL in Prometheus and got trendline(Evaluated as true).
However when I queried ALERTS metric with identical label set and timestamp, I couldn't find any alert is fired, is it possible?
Basically the alert is not evaluated as true, hence should not be alertmanager's problem.
Then I've inspected some metric relevant to Prometheus performance itself, like:

prometheus_rule_group_iterations_missed_total: 0(represent the evaluation is never skipped).
prometheus_rule_group_last_duration_seconds: around 20~35secs(represent all rules in rule group are all evaluated, < 1-min default setting)
Basic infra. check: Our Prometheus is deployed on K8S, and no limitation is hit checked in CPU, MEM, process, file-system, etc.

Should I inspect more metrics which I missed?
Sorry that I can't attach any screenshots for PD due to our company's policy.
